# How can I add a horizontal line (equilibrium) to Vector Plot in Mathematica

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

Equilibrium solution for y'=3-2y is at y=3/2 and I would like to add the line y=3/2 to direction field plotted using VectorPlot function. How to do?

The additional code below does it.

```
points = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 
    2}, {2, 2}};

datplot = 
  VectorPlot[{1, 3 - 2 y}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
   VectorPoints -> points, VectorScale -> {Automatic, Automatic, None},
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[points]}];

fitplot = Plot[y = 3/2, {y, 0, 2}];
{Show[datplot, fitplot]}
```

Mary A. Marion

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[points]}
```

to

```
Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[points], Line[{{0,3/2},{2,3/2}}]}
```

Comment: Bill, That resulted in an error but I found another way. Try

Comment: Ah! scrape-n-paste missed the trailing `}` on that line. I apologize. Edited to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will compute the solution*:

```
points = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 1},
    {0, 2}, {1,2}, {2, 2}};

datplot = 
  VectorPlot[{1, 3 - 2 y}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
  VectorPoints -> points, VectorScale -> {Automatic, Automatic, None},
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[points], 
    Line[{{0, 3/2}, {2, 3/2}}]}]
```

- See Bill's input above.